# Confuse in enabling package repository

Tags: puppet, puppetdb

I am having trouble installing puppetdb so I am back tracking my steps and try to find out my error. So I am to enable puppet package repositories before I install puppetdb shown in this guide. https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#open-source-repositories

My current problem: When I typed `sudo service puppetdb start` it saids "puppetdb: unrecongize service" I don't get it. I followed the guide in "install puppetdb via module" without trouble.

I use linuxmint 17:

```
sudo wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

Question. Do I have to do sudo dpkg for all the .deb files listed in https://apt.puppetlabs.com/? or just the precise should suffice for puppetdb and puppetdb terminus installation.

Answer (score 0):

If Linux Mint 17 is equivalent to Ubuntu Precise, than the steps you've provided should be enough to enable the Puppet Labs packaging repos. These do indeed contain `puppetdb` and `puppetdb-terminus`.

As far as the rest of your problem, you need to reread the documentation provided here:

https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/latest/install_via_module.html

I'm pretty sure you're mixing documentation up just by looking at the command you had fail earlier (`sudo service puppetdb start`). The module documentation doesn't require you to start `puppetdb` manually like this, the module does this for you. On the other hand, the package based installation does ask you to do this. I think you've gotten mixed up somewhere perhaps.

So please take another look at the docs and follow them to the letter. And if you have problems provide a transcript (in a gist or pastie potentially) of the full steps as per the docs and where it broke. You've said you followed the documentation without trouble, but clearly there was trouble somewhere, and without proper visibility it makes it hard to judge where you went wrong.